# maxidiagram found by kpsewhich, but not pdflatex

Tags: errors, packages, kpathsea

I'm trying to `\usepackage{MaxiDiagram}` on Arch Linux, but `pdflatex` complains:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `MaxiDiagram.sty' not found.
```

Running `kpsewhich MaxiDiagram` reports that the file exists at `/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/borceux/MaxiDiagram`.

Copying that file to `MaxiDiagram.sty` in the working directory seems to get further, although it's now complaining:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./book.2.6.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsbook.cls
Document Class: amsbook 2015/03/04 v2.20.2
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty

Package amsfonts Warning: The 'psamsfonts' option is obsolete in AMSFonts v3.

)) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/borceux/MaxiDiagram
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)

/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/borceux/MaxiDiagram:784: LaTeX Error: Command
 \bold already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

What can I do to fix this?

(The LaTeX source I'm working with is not authored by me; It was probably written on a windows system, not sure with what software)

---

Minimal Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{MaxiDiagram}
\begin{document}
Hi!
\end{document}
```

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: File \`maxidiagram.sty' not found.` indicates yiu used `\usepackage{maxidiagram}` not `\usepackage{MaxiDiagram} `

Comment: I've actually tried both. Updated the question to be consistent

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)` \usepackage{MaxiDiagram}` is definitely the correct way to load the package. `LaTeX Error: Command \bold already defined.` is saying there's some sort of clash with multiple definitions of `\bold` causing the problem. Could you construct a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I've added a minimal example for the first error. Using `\input` instead of `\usepackage` works (but I'd prefer to fix my tex setup than edit the source). Still working on a minimal example for the `bold` issue. Something seems to be including `MaxiDiagram` twice.

Comment: your tex setup is correct, the file is distributed without  extension, if the existing document is loading it with `\usepackage` then that was a local copy of the file with a .sty name, as you did

Comment: I see. Gosh. Hope the file wasn't modified to fix the bold issue.

Comment: @cfr actually it is, it's full of `\newcommand` (despite being in tex/generic in texlive, try tex MaxiDiagram and you'll see:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I know. I deleted my comment here and left you a comment instead. It shouldn't do this, surely?

Comment: Do you load `amssymb` before `MaxiDiagram` by any chance?

Comment: Are you really sure you want to use those ancient macros for diagrams? There are much better packages nowadays.

Comment: I'm actually compiling a book that someone else has already written, so I've got no choice in the matter :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 kpsewhich MaxiDiagram
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/borceux/MaxiDiagram
```

indicates the file is called `MaxiDiagram` not `MaxiDiagram.sty` so it needs to be input via

```
\input{MaxiDiagram}
```

Your second error shows you have a  `MaxiDiagram.sty` in your local directory, but it doesn't have that name in texlive or CTAN.

You haven't shown a reproducible test but if you have two packages defining `\bold` you can "undefine" it after loading the first with

```
`\let\bold\undefined`
```

but of course then you lose that definition and may or may not break the first package, depending on how it uses the command.

Comment: Why does it use `\newcommand` at all? Let alone to define `\bold`? Shouldn't a `generic` file avoid LaTeX commands?

Comment: I'm not sure. There's also an `unbold` command. From my (poor) understanding, I think it's being used in some kind of sub-environment, for creating diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested as I have no idea how to use `diagram` correctly since the documentation uses an encoding which appears to me as gobbledygook or little twiddly boxes, depending on the application I use to view it.

I'm assuming you load `amssymb` before `MaxiDiagram`. If so, you might try the following since `amssymb`'s `\bold{}` just prints a warning telling you to use `\mathbf{}` instead anyway.

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
\let\bold\undefined % \bold is obsolete anyway
\input{MaxiDiagram}
\let\diagbold\bold
\renewcommand{\bold}{\ifdiagram\diagbold\else\mathbf\fi}
```

`MaxiDiagram`'s `\bold{}` produces an error message if `\diagramfalse` by default. This redefines it to use `\mathbf{}` instead.

`MaxiDiagram` either should not be in `generic` or it should not be using LaTeX commands.

Also, I would not trust it at all .... It looks as if it is designed to maximise the risk of conflicts with as many packages as possible.